# Can I create a CDF from Mathematica 7?

Tags: cdf-format, version-7

I am almost sure I remember seeing an online tool on the Wolframs website for creating CDF's for *Mathematica* users with version 7. Am I right? And if so, where can I find it?

Comment: If you google on "convert  mathematica 7 notebook to cdf format",  you will find the [link](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/interactivedeployment/publish/) as the first hit.

Answer (score 2):

You still seem to be able to do that [here](http://www.wolfram.com/solutions/interactivedeployment/publish/).